# CQRS & PurchaseOrder AggregateRoot

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs, domain-model, aggregateroot

i am new to CQRS & DDD and for a practice i am using MS WideWorldImporters database, at the moment i am stuck on purchase order placement command, to say the truth i don't know how it should look like, can you guide me?
   Should i have 1 PlaceOrderCommand and handler should use it to create PurchaseOrder fill its OrderLines and than save. if yes, how Command should look like when domain models looks like:

Sample Domain Model:

```
public class PurchaseOrder : AggregateRoot<int>
{
    private PurchaseOrder(int id, int supplierID, DateTime orderDate, int deliveryMethodID, int contactPersonID) : base(id)
    {
        SupplierID = supplierID;
        OrderDate = orderDate;
        DeliveryMethodID = deliveryMethodID;
        ContactPersonID = contactPersonID;
    }

    public List<PurchaseOrderLine> PurchaseOrderLines { get; private set; }
    public int SupplierID { get; private set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; private set; }
    public int DeliveryMethodID { get; private set; }
    public int ContactPersonID { get; private set; }

    public static PurchaseOrder CreatePurchaseOrder(int supplierID, int deliveryMethodID, int contactPersonID)
    {
        return new PurchaseOrder(1, supplierID, DateTime.Now, deliveryMethodID, contactPersonID);
    }

    public void AddPurchaseOrderLine(int stockItemID)
    {
        PurchaseOrderLines.Add(new PurchaseOrderLine(this.Id, stockItemID));
    }
}
```

Sample Command Handler:

```
    public class PurchaseOrdersCommandHandler : 
    ICommandHandler<PlacePurchaseOrder>
{
    private readonly IPurchaseOrderRepository purchaseOrderRepository;

    public PurchaseOrdersCommandHandler(IPurchaseOrderRepository purchaseOrderRepository)
    {
        this.purchaseOrderRepository = purchaseOrderRepository;
    }

    public void Handle(PlacePurchaseOrder command)
    {
        // TODO: based on command Create Purchase order with its line items and save it to db as a whole
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just do something like this?

```
public void Handle(PlacePurchaseOrder command)
{
    var purchaseOrder = PurchaseOrder.CreatePurchaseOrder(command.id, command.upplierID, command.orderDate, command.deliveryMethodID, command.contactPersonID);
    foreach(int stockItemID in command.OrderLines)
    {
        purchaseOrder.AddPurchaseOrderLine(stockItemID)
    }
    this.purchaseOrderRepository.Save(purchaseOrder);
}
```

Comment: If it's just a list of ints I don't see why not.

Comment: I'd try and avoid big nested object graphs in commands as a general guideline but if having a list of ints to represent the purchase order line items matches the business process then I think it's fine :)

Comment: problem is that. i cant have list of ints, when order is placed it is placed as one object, and its orderlines cant be changed. All you can do is FinalizeOrder or CancellOrder and orderline is not only stockIDs, its also quantity unitprice etc

Comment: Your example has a public method AddPurchaseOrderLine which contradicts your statement that OrdeLines cannot be changed once the object is created. If this is the case model it this way by passing the OrderLines in the constructor and making it immutable

Comment: I'd probably still adopt the approach in my answer if the OrderLines are objects rather than ints